# Dependency Injection on an N-Tier solution - Remove Boilerplate

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, n-tier-architecture

I am creating a solution that has an API (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web), domain (Microsoft.NET.Sdk), and MVC projects (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web) targeting .NET 8.

In my domain I have two classes that look like this:

```c#
public class ApplicationUserQuery
{

    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public ApplicationUserQuery(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    // ...
}

public class ApplicationUserService
{

    private readonly ApplicationUserQuery _applicationUserQuery;

    public ApplicationUserService(ApplicationUserQuery applicationUserQuery)
    {
        _applicationUserQuery = applicationUserQuery;
    }

    // ...
}
```

To use the classes in my API project I am doing the following in my Program.cs:

```c#
var applicationDatabaseConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDatabase");
if (applicationDatabaseConnectionString == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(applicationDatabaseConnectionString));
}
builder.Services.AddScoped(_ => new ApplicationUserQuery(applicationDatabaseConnectionString));
builder.Services.AddScoped<ApplicationUserService>();
```

This works, but it seems like a lot of boilerplate just for two classes and will continue to grow for every service/query class I create in my domain. Is there anyway to simplify this using the built-in .NET core stuff? I'm wanting to avoid using a 3rd party library like Ninject because of issues I have had with Ninject in particular on projects I do at work.

Comment: How many classes in your application will you have that take a direct dependency on a query string? In my experience you would only have one or just a few, even for big applications. If you have many query components that take direct dependency on query string, you might consider pulling that string out and hiding it behind an abstraction of some sort. This will immediately simplify registration, and likely also simplify those classes themselves.

Comment: Research options and options validation on startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET Extensions DI is intended to be used like the example you provided. It is a rudimentary tool that you can build upon if you like, it has very little opinions. Features like named (keyed) services was just introduced in .NET 8, years after initial release.

If you want to auto-register the dependencies, use a different library or implement it yourself - e.g. take the domain `Assembly`, enumerate all types that end with `"Query"` and register them as scoped, it's not that much code and you have it under your control.

Comment: _" very little opinions"_ - did you mean to write "options" ?

Comment: No, I meant to write _opinions_ :) My understanding is that other frameworks may offer less of what OP calls boilerplate. The cost is that they need to introduce strategies to achieve this. These are based on opinions of the framework authors. If a consumer does what they envisioned as the good approach, it will work great. If a consumer needs something else, it won't.

Comment: Ah, I see. Now it's clear.

Comment: I have edited the answer because the wording was truly unclear, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I think I'm going to mark this as the answer. After mulling over your suggestion I think what I'll do is create a "RegisterDependencies" class with a static method called "RegisterQueries", use reflection to call `AddScoped`, and then call the method in my Program.cs file.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek, you mention "auto-wire," but Auto-Wiring is "the ability to automatically compose an object graph from maps between abstractions and concrete types by making use of type information supplied b y the compiler and the Common Language Runtime." (source [DIPP&P](https://mng.bz/BYNl)). MS.DI fully supports Auto-Wiring. You supposedly mean Auto-Registration, which is "the ability to  register components based on a certain convention in the DI Container bu scanning one or more assemblies for implementations of desired abstractions." MS.DI lacks Auto-Registration.

Comment: @Steven I'm sorry, does that mean that - according to the book - auto-wiring is at time of instantiation and auto-registration is at time of configuration?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. Auto-Wiring just means that you tell the container e.g. `AddTransient<IMyService, ServiceImpl>()` and it will create `ServiceImpl` with its dependencies based on the definition of its constructor. Auto-Registration, on the other hand, could mean you ask the container to register all classes whose name ends with "Repository" by their defined interface from your data layer assembly. The container will then register them as a 'batch', which is why Auto-Registration is sometimes referred to as Batch-Registration.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain. I have so far only seen the term auto-wiring used for what you call auto-registration. This is with frameworks such as Castle Windsor or in general with Java or PHP. I have edited the answer to use the term as proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just inject `IConfiguration` like this

```
public class ApplicationUserQuery
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public ApplicationUserQuery(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _connectionString = config["ApplicationDatabase"];
        // do you really need this checking?
        // just make an extension method in another file called something like HostExtensions.cs and call them in the program.cs for any null config valules
        // checks if you really need to.
        if(string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(_connectionString) {//throw exception}
    }
}
```

Then in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ApplicationUserQuery>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ApplicationUserService>();
```

Judging just by what you posted (I don't have an overview of what your architecture looks like) it looks like you have a service layer then a repo layer. For what? Why do need those separation of concerns? I could be wrong (Because I don't know what you're building) but it looks like you're over architecting a solution for no reason. Hence all the boiler plate code you're writing.

Comment: You still have to add the AddScoped in the Program.cs for every class. That’s what I’m trying to avoid.

Comment: @David you can have a look into the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options), but yes, you'll have to do some DI registration for settings/options/config (whatever you want to call it). There's no way around that outside of hard-codding (which I assume we agree is off the table). Upside is: you can have the settings validated using DataAnnotations instead of hardcoding the tests and it will show you errors right at startup.